# how to remove 1 key using plutil?

Tags: key

Data is a file:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPEplistPUBLIC"-//Apple//DTDPLIST1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plistversion="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>FairPlayKeyData</key>
    <data>LS0tLS1CRU5FUi0tLS0tCg==</data>
    <key>LDActivationVersion</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>unbrick</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WildcardTicketToRemove</key>
    <data>MIICqgsdAgMBAAE=</data>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to remove this data:

```
<key>WildcardTicketToRemove</key>
<data>MIICqgsdAgMBAAE=</data>
```

i try:

```
plutil -remove WildcardTicketToRemove file
```

output:

> Property List error: Encountered unknown tag plistversion="1.0" on
> line 3 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and
> option to allow fragments not set.

Answer (score 0):

Your PLIST file is incorrect, it should start with `<plist version="1.0">` instead of `<plistversion="1.0">`.